# How to count occurences of value in array?

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of times `0` appears in my array.

All other answers tell me to create a dataframe, I would like to know how to count the occurences of a value **in an array**, as I don't wan't to clutter my environment with unnecessary data.

For example:

```
array <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1)
value_to_count <- 0
count <- someFunction(array, value_to_count)
```

The variable `count` should == 3.

Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the sum function in combination with the == operator to achieve this. In your example:

```html
array <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1)
value_to_count <- 0
count <- sum(array == value_to_count)
```

count will equal 3, as expected. What this does is create a logical vector with TRUE where the value in the array is equal to value_to_count and FALSE otherwise. The sum function then counts the number of TRUE values, which is the number of occurrences of the value you're looking for.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)